# Github oauth filter out repos that have issues disabled

Tags: javascript, api, http, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm trying to return a list of all my repos that have/can have issues (ie. not those with issues `disabled`);

The url to fetch issues is:
https://api.github.com/repos/schme16/barcode/issues and as you can see it just returns        `{message: "Issues are disabled for this repo"}` as this repo does indeed have them disabled

That behavior is fine as I can just handle the 'error', but I'd rather just not get the repos that will 'error' (ie. then ones with issues disabled).

Currently my repo fetch address is: https://api.github.com/users/schme16/repos but as mentioned it returns ALL of my repos, irrespective of issues status.

**Extra info**: All of my requests are being sent with the correct and current `access_token`, but for security they are not shown here.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to filter the response from `https://api.github.com/users/schme16/repos` by objects with the `has_issues` attribute equal to `false`, e.g., (pseudo-code not really JavaScript)

```
for obj in json do
    if obj.has_issues then
       fetch_issues()
    endif
endfor
```

The listing of a user's repositories does have that information even though the [documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) doesn't explicitly state that it does.

Comment: I had just come across that when you posted! I assume then that therees no way to filter it server side then? (not that there's a problem with client siding it and I'll mark you answer as correct)

Comment: @ShaneGadsby there isn't a parameter to send to filter that as best as I know. You could, however, propose the idea to the API team via the [support link](https://github.com/contact). Make sure you put API in the subject/title so it goes right to the API team.